# Rails is not recognizing an installed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I tried to install the ruby-hmac gem

If I do "gem list", I see it is installed:

```
...
RedCloth (3.0.4)
ruby-hmac (0.3.2)
ruby-openid (1.1.4)
...
```

However when I try to include it in my Rails project...

```
config.gem "ruby-hmac"
```

I get an error:

```
Missing these required gems:
  ruby-hmac  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.6.287 at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.4 at /Users/TAmoyal/.gem/ruby/1.8, /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8, /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

So I take a look at my gems directory...

```
Macintosh-2:bhr TAmoyal$ ls -al /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  admin   408 Jun 28 23:14 rake-0.8.7/
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  admin   272 Dec  5 00:34 ruby-hmac-0.3.2/
drwxr-xr-x   9 root  admin   306 Jun 28 23:35 rubyforge-1.0.3/
```

permissions look fine so I try to include another gem from that same directory:

```
config.gem 'javan-whenever', :lib => false, :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

And the console loads fine.  For some reason it cannot see ruby-hmac but it sees another gem that appears on gem list and is also installed in the same directory with the same permissions.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this?  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to provide a `:lib` option for our config.gem like

```
config.gem "ruby-hmac", :lib => 'ruby_hmac'
```

Some gems do have a lib name that is different from the gem name. I'm not exactly sure what the lib name for the ruby-hmac gem would be. Try looking the at the docs for clues.

Comment: that was it...i didn't know the "lib" param was actually required and there was nothing in the docs about it.  just took a guess based on your answer

Comment: I encountered the same error tonight with the OpenID gem; here is the "lib" value that worked in this case: config.gem "ruby-openid", :lib => "openid"